# How to change text except its span

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

How can we change the text data from except span text?

```
<h2 id="nameUser" >Muhammed <span> mobile :989 531 9991</span></h2>
```

Is there any solution to change `h2` except span?

Comment: Use not() - http://api.jquery.com/not/

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery

Comment: @JayBlanchard `not()` won't work in this situation. http://jsbin.com/ayedub/2/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/4mThh/) example may help you to change father element without changing child elements:

```
var content= $('#nameUser').children();
$('#nameUser').text('Altered Text').append(content);​
```

Comment: Note that this will also remove event handlers for elements inside the node.

Answer (score 4):

`.contents()` returns a collection of nodes, including text nodes. So in your case this would work:

```
$('#nameUser').contents()​​​​​​​​[0].nodeValue = 'Another name';​​
```

If you want to get every node except the SPAN, try:

```
$('#nameUser').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeName != 'SPAN';
}).​each(function(i) {
    // modify each text node
    this.nodeValue = 'name '+i;
});​​​​​
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/Vks82/

Comment: This one is good because it will retain the order of things inside the h2 tag if there are span children before and after the text to be modified. Where as most of the other examples do not. http://jsbin.com/ayedub/4/edit

Answer (score 2):

Search for the first textnode in childNodes of the h2 element. Change the value of the textnode.

```
var element = document.getElementById('nameUser');
element.childNodes[0].nodeValue = 'New String';
```

..should work. Only for this example, because the first childnode is the textnode you want, you don't have to search for it. Otherwise you do..

Comment: @maanu I wasn't aware of this issue, but IE counts childNodes differently from other browsers (firefox). Does this help you? http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?156010-childNodes-in-Firefox-vs-IE&s=d295e3e1c2ff528c94360787920ae41e&p=782524#post782524 , alternatively you might want to use gdoron's method, if it suits you better and you're fine with using jQuery for this particular problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#nameUser').contents().each(function() {
    if (this.nodeType == 3) 
        this.data = "The text you want here";
});​
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/nPh3S/)

Comment: nice usage of [nodeType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.nodeType?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=nodeType)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by saving the children first here is a codepen of it working.

http://codepen.io/beckje01/pen/sGLot

```
var h2 = $('#nameUser');
var elmsToSave = h2.children();

h2.empty();
h2.text('bob');
h2.append(elmsToSave);
```

As pointed out in the comments this will only work if the text to change is first.

Answer (score 0):

This will work not only for `span` but also for any other element which you want the text without the text of it's children.

```
$("#nameUser")
    .clone()   
    .children()
    .remove()  
    .end()  
    .text();
```

For change the text I've create a simple jQuery function:

```
replaceTextWith = function($element, $replacement){
    $oldText = $element.clone().children().remove().end().text();
    $element.text($element.text().replace($oldText, $replacement));
}

replaceTextWith($("#nameUser"), "Bruno"); //usage
```

Here's a live example working on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brunovieira/7ar6K/1)

Comment: Are you sure it will work?! can you give us a live example at http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Yes I'm sure, I'll fiddle it

Comment: That looks like it will return the text without the span, but the OP wanted to modify it.

Comment: Oh man! I really thought he want just to get the text. I'll edit it. It's possible

Comment: Now it works as it should! Sorry for not reading it right in the first time

Comment: This will also remove the SPAN element (or any other HTML).

Comment: Actually this won't remove anything since it's working with a clone of the object. But yes, this works for any other element which is a child of the $element object.

Answer (score 0):

try this ...

```
<h2 id="nameUser" >Muhammed <span id="nameUserSpan"> mobile :989 531 9991</span></h2>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var inspan= $("#nameUserSpan").html();
    var newuser='New User';
    $("#nameUser").html('');
    $("#nameUser").html(newuser + '<span id="nameUserSpan">' + inspan + '</span>');
});
</script>
```